# Invoking camera from within my application through button click

Tags: android, camera, invoke

Completely new to this and to Android development, looking for a bit of help if possible. I am developing my first application for Android at the moment and have very little coding experience...I basically have an application at the moment that is allowing me to add/delete/update users to and from a sqlite database. I am looking for a way just to add a button on the main homepage that allows me to access the camera and take a picture. The main activity is simply a page with buttons to add/delete etc:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
            if (editText.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newEntry);
                editText.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("Please enter a name!");
            }

        }
    });

    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("User Added!");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




}
}
```

The code I have for implementing the camera is shown below(it works for invoking the camera and taking a picture but only from the camera outside the application)

Is it possible for me to just a button on the main activity page that allows me to "take picture" from within the application

(code for invoking camera)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void getPhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 1) {


        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager. PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            getPhoto();

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

    } else{

        getPhoto();
    }




}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry if the question seems stupid, completely new to Android development and new to coding so I am very unsure.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: Strange problem. You have already so much buttons. Just look how it is done there. Just add an extra button in the .xml layout file R.layout.activity_main. Then add a little code in onCreate(). Add an onClickListener for the new button.

Comment: Whats the issue ? Just add a button in xml and fire camera intent on its Click.??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are looking for, but here is code to take a picture : 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

To add the button, you need to add it in the layout then get the reference in your activity class with the findViewById method

Hope this help

Comment: Ok thanks, I basically just added a new button to the xml file to take a picture when clicked:   btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });   I can now access the camera when I click the button and it allows me to take a picture etc. just need to figure out a way to allow me to store the images in my app now, thanks again